# Get "error: cannot access FragmentActivity" after upgrade my Android SDK

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-fragmentactivity

I have an Android application that based on `libuvccamera` library.

My problem is came after upgrading my SDK to the latest one.

When I'm trying to "Make Project" it's working well.

But when I'm trying to run the project then I've got the following error message:

> error: cannot access FragmentActivity
>
> class file for android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity not found
>
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

in this specific line:

```
baseActivity.setPath(path);
```

This line is part of this function:

```
public void handleUpdateMedia(final String path) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG_THREAD, "handleUpdateMedia:path=" + path);
            mHandler.setPath(path);
            final Activity parent=mWeakParent.get();

            BaseActivity baseActivity=(BaseActivity) parent;
            if (baseActivity != null) {
                baseActivity.setPath(path);
            }
            final boolean released=(mHandler == null) || mHandler.mReleased;
            if (parent != null && parent.getApplicationContext() != null) {
                try {
                    if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "MediaScannerConnection#scanFile");
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(parent.getApplicationContext(), new String[]{path}, null, null);
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "handleUpdateMedia:", e);
                }
                if (released || parent.isDestroyed())
                    handleRelease();
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "MainActivity already destroyed");
                // give up to add this movie to MediaStore now.
                // Seeing this movie on Gallery app etc. will take a lot of time.
                handleRelease();
            }
        }
```

Which is located in `usbCameraCommon` library (one of the libraries used by libuvccamera library).

Does anybody else faced with this kind of issue?

Thanks

Comment: Your libuvccamera is using a deprecated FragmentActivity class which is removed on the newest support library. You need to update it using AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but there is better solution, I really appreciate if someone can write it more detailed here and I'll explain myself.

The reason the project was failed was the wrong using of `implementation` and `api` in the gradle file of libuvccamera project.

I just used `implementation` for all the dependencies projects which now I know it is wrong, but I'm still don't understand the differences between them.

So the code that down't work was:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: new File(buildDir, 'libs'), include: '*.jar')
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    implementation ("com.serenegiant:common:${commonLibVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

And when I return the old code it works:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: new File(buildDir, 'libs'), include: '*.jar')
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile ("com.serenegiant:common:${commonLibVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

I really appreciate if someone can solved it the right way with a little bit of explanation.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I found the right solution but still appreciate for some explanation why it is work:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: new File(buildDir, 'libs'), include: '*.jar')
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
    api 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    api("com.serenegiant:common:${commonLibVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```